# Is the "Fibonacci square tiling" of Fibonacci-sided rectangles always optimal?

Tags: fibonacci-numbers, tiling

Is an optimal square tiling of a rectangle with side lengths of successive Fibonacci numbers always the sequence of Fibonacci numbers, as in the picture below?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "optimal"? I think there are many ways for covering a $13\times 8$ rectangle with squares.

Comment: But in every way to cover the $F_n\times F_{n+1}$ rectangle using just $n$ squares the squares must be of size $F_1,\ldots, F_n$. So it's optimal in the number of squares used.

Comment: Try induction...